# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden when uploading file angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, file, directive, angular-services

I am creating a web app in which I am storing user images in my folder, after a while I found an example which helps me,

but I am getting the error

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory.

and my code is

source

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
</head>
```

body

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="file" file-model="myFile" />
        <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
        <a href="#" ng-click="a()">save</a>
    </div>
```

script

```
 <script>
        //inject angular file upload directives and services.
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                    var modelSetter = model.assign;

                    element.bind('change', function () {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);

        myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
            this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('file', file);
                $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
                })
                .success(function () {
                })
                .error(function () {
                });
            }
        }]);

        myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function ($scope, fileUpload) {
            $scope.a = function () {
                console.log('called');
            }
            $scope.uploadFile = function () {
                console.log('called');
                var file = $scope.myFile;
                console.log('file is ');
                console.dir(file);
                var uploadUrl = "http://localhost:9206//file//";
                fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            };
        }]);

    </script>
```

and the url is

> http://localhost:9206//file//

let me explain this

this is my one page application, I want to save image in my folder called file,

when a user uploaded his/her image, the image should be stored in the folder,

but instead of this I am getting this error

> (HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden)

what I need to do now?

Comment: Reading the error it looks like the directory / folder does not give permission to write / read from it. Check your service permissions for the folders you are interested in. If you are using a Linux distribution, make sure you go "ls -la" and check the read / write / execute parameters. It appears it's an error derived from permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem can be fixed by enabling the IIS. You can enable and configure the Internet Information Service (IIS) on your computer (given that you are using localhost) by following the instructions on this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: are you using windows localhost or a LAMP host (linux) ?

Comment: using localhost

Comment: yes, but on windows system or linux system?

What kind of local server are you running?